# Delete interlinked tables data using one query

Tags: oracle, query, delete

I want to write the database query to delete the data from multiple interlinked tables. 
Below is the structure of the database:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE1 (
  ID NUMBER(10),
  TABLE2_ID NUMBER(10),
  TABLE3_ID NUMBER(10),
  DATA VARCHAR2(200)
);

INSERT INTO TABLE1
  (ID, TABLE2_ID, TABLE3_ID, DATA)
VALUES
  ('1', '1', '1', 'TEST');




CREATE TABLE TABLE2 (
  ID NUMBER(10),
  DATA VARCHAR2(200)
);

INSERT INTO TABLE2
  (ID, DATA)
VALUES
  ('1', 'TABLE 2 DATA');



CREATE TABLE TABLE3 (
  ID NUMBER(10),
  DATA VARCHAR2(200)
);

INSERT INTO TABLE3
  (ID, DATA)
VALUES
  ('1', 'TABLE 3 DATA');



CREATE TABLE TABLE1_TABLE4_JOIN_TABLE (
  TABLE1_ID NUMBER(10),
  TABLE4_ID NUMBER(10)
);

INSERT INTO TABLE1_TABLE4_JOIN_TABLE
  (TABLE1_ID, TABLE4_ID)
   SELECT '1', '1' FROM dual UNION ALL 
   SELECT '1', '2' FROM dual UNION ALL 
   SELECT '1', '3' FROM dual;



CREATE TABLE TABLE4 (
  ID NUMBER(10),
  TABLE5_ID NUMBER(10),
  DATA VARCHAR2(200)
);

INSERT INTO TABLE4
  (ID, TABLE5_ID, DATA)
   SELECT '1', '1', 'TABLE 4 DATA 1' FROM dual UNION ALL 
   SELECT '2', '2', 'TABLE 4 DATA 2' FROM dual UNION ALL 
   SELECT '3', '3', 'TABLE 4 DATA 3' FROM dual;



CREATE TABLE TABLE5 (
  ID NUMBER(10),
  DATA VARCHAR2(200)
);

INSERT INTO TABLE5
  (ID, DATA)
   SELECT '1', 'TABLE 5 DATA 1' FROM dual UNION ALL 
   SELECT '2', 'TABLE 5 DATA 2' FROM dual UNION ALL 
   SELECT '3', 'TABLE 5 DATA 3' FROM dual;



TABLE1:
+----+-----------+-----------+------+
| ID | TABLE2_ID | TABLE3_ID | DATA |
+----+-----------+-----------+------+
|  1 |         1 |         1 | TEST |
+----+-----------+-----------+------+


TABLE2:
+----+--------------+
| ID |     DATA     |
+----+--------------+
|  1 | TABLE 2 DATA |
+----+--------------+

TABLE3:
+----+--------------+
| ID |     DATA     |
+----+--------------+
|  1 | TABLE 3 DATA |
+----+--------------+


TABLE1_TABLE4_JOIN_TABLE:
+-----------+-----------+
| TABLE1_ID | TABLE4_ID |
+-----------+-----------+
|         1 |         1 |
|         1 |         2 |
|         1 |         3 |
+-----------+-----------+

TABLE4:
+----+-----------+----------------+
| ID | TABLE5_ID |      DATA      |
+----+-----------+----------------+
|  1 |         1 | TABLE 4 DATA 1 |
|  2 |         2 | TABLE 4 DATA 2 |
|  3 |         3 | TABLE 4 DATA 3 |
+----+-----------+----------------+

TABLE5:
+----+----------------+
| ID |      DATA      |
+----+----------------+
|  1 | TABLE 5 DATA 1 |
|  2 | TABLE 5 DATA 2 |
|  3 | TABLE 5 DATA 3 |
+----+----------------+
```

I have not shown the foreign key constraints in the schema above but all foreign keys are set up in the database.

I want to delete everything which is linked to table1.id = [someid]

```
select TABLE1.*,TABLE2.*,TABLE3.*,TABLE4.*,TABLE5.*,TABLE1_TABLE4_JOIN_TABLE.* from TABLE1
inner join TABLE2 on TABLE1.TABLE2_ID = TABLE2.ID
inner join TABLE3 on TABLE1.TABLE3_ID = TABLE3.ID
inner join TABLE1_TABLE4_JOIN_TABLE on TABLE1.ID = TABLE1_TABLE4_JOIN_TABLE.TABLE1_ID
inner join TABLE4 on TABLE4.ID = TABLE1_TABLE4_JOIN_TABLE.TABLE4_ID
inner join TABLE5 on TABLE5.ID = TABLE4.TABLE5_ID
where TABLE1.ID =1;
```

I tried the above select query with delete from but it's not deleting the data.

Please suggest the best way to delete these.

Comment: If you want to delete from 5 different tables, you'll need 5 different `DELETE` statements

Comment: "I have not shown the foreign key constraints" - Why not? Those are important for such an operation. If you have your foreign keys defined with the `ON DELETE CASCADE` option, a simple `DELETE FROM TABLE1 WHERE ID  = :someid;` will delete the data from all tables following the foreign key constraints.